# Можно ли уничтожить создаваемый объект в конструкторе PHP? Или что делать если передаваемые аргументы не валидны

Tags: php

Создаем объект Circle с радиусом меньше или равно 0, то есть такой круг заведомо не может существовать. Можно ли такой объект уничтожить на стадии конструктора, например чтобы конструктор не создал объект по итогу, а вернул NULL? Ну или напишите как правильно обрабатывать подобные случаи.

```
class Circle
{
    private $radius;
    public function __construct(int $radius)
    {   
        if ($radius > 0) {
            $this->radius = $radius;
        } else {
            $this->radius = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Выбросить исключение?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14719096)

Comment: Так?

    public function __construct(int $radius)
    {   
        try {
            if ($radius > 0) {
                $this->radius = $radius;
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

Все равно объект создается и возвращается, а не NULL

Comment: сударь, исключение выбрасывают не для того, чтобы его тут же поймать и избавиться. Ловить его должен в данном случае внешний код. а конструктор вообще не имеет return со значением.

Comment: То есть на стадии конструктора объект в любом случае придется создать, даже если были переданы невалидные данные, как в моем примере?

Comment: @ИгорьМихайлов нет. см. пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742845/6104996

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если аргументы вас не устраивают, и ситуация явно исключительная, логично выбросить какое-нить условное `InvalidArgumentException`. Обрабатывать данную ситуацию, конечно, должен вызывающий код.

Другим вариантом решения проблемы будет создание экземпляра класса через статический метод, сделав конструктор приватным, например, так:

```
class Circle {
    
    private $r = 0;

    private function __construct(int $r){
        $this->r = $r;
    }
    
    public static function new(int $r){
        if($r <= 0) return null;
        return new self($r);
    }
}


$x = Circle::new(10);
print_r($x);
```

Но в любом случае, вызывающий код должен выполнять либо работу по отлову исключений, либо проверки результата создания на null.

Comment: Корректно ли возвращать null? Может использовать nullable object?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!